# Where to place @produces/@consumes Annotationen?

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy

If all endpoints of a ressource return/consume the same application header then you don't need to place the annotations above every single endpoint. Instead you can place it just above the ressource. Is that right in case of RestEasy ??

For example:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
class MyResource{

    // endpoint 1
    // endpoint 2
    // endpoint 3
}
```

So all endpoints will return json format ??

Comment: btw there is no need to add `charset=utf-8`. This is the default encoding according to [the specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) and all major browsers have been complying with it for several years now.

Comment: Yes, that's what the annotation on the class if meant to do